# Multiple Json Files or A single file with multiple arrays

Tags: arrays, json

I have a large blob (azure) file with 10k json objects in a single array.  This does not perform because of its size.  As I look to re-architect it, I can either create multiple files with a single array in each of 500-1000 objects or I could keep the one file, but burst the single array into an array of arrays-- maybe 10 arrays of 1000 objects each.

For simplicity, I'd rather break into multiple files.  However, I thought this was worth asking the question and seeing if there was something to be learned in the answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would think this depends strongly on your use-case. The multiple files or multiple arrays you create will partition your data somehow: will the partitions be used mostly together or mostly separate? I.e. will there be a lot of cases in which you only read one or a small number of the partitions?

If the answer is "yes, I will usually only care about a small number of partitions" then creating multiple files will save you having to deal with most of your data on most of your calls. If the answer is "no, I will usually need either 1.) all/most of my data or 2.) data from all/most of my partitions" then you probably want to keep one file just to avoid having to *open* many files every time.

I'll add: in this latter case, it may well turn out that the file structure (one array vs an array-of-arrays) doesn't change things very much, since a full scan is a full scan is a full scan etc. If that's the case, then you may need to start thinking about how to move to the prior case where you partition your data so that your calls fall neatly within few partitions, or how to move to a different data format.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts.  Behind my comment was kind of a fundamental question about JSON parsing.  Is there really any difference between a single array with 20k children versus an array of 20 objects, each containing 1,000 children.

My assumption is no-- as you say a full scan is a full scan.  However, if there was some efficiency in creating the nesting then it would avoid creating multiple file objects.

Comment: Say my JSON file reader has a `getNextObject` method, sort of like a regular reader's `getNextLine`. At the low level, the JSON reader will have to iterate to find the end of the next object - a `}`, basically. At a high level, once the object is returned to me, I can choose to keep it in memory or decide it's irrelevant and throw it away. So to answer your question: you'll have to iterate no matter what, but if you have more objects you can use the objects to, for example: 1.) know what sub-objects are relevant, i.e. should be kept and 2.) know whether you can stop iterating before file end

Comment: Note that this is all dependent on 1.) partitioning the data into sub-objects in a useful way and 2.) giving the sub-objects metadata which lets you quickly tell which are relevant and which are not